# Code not checking length using pattern attribute HTML

Tags: html, xampp

Trying to get the program to require a min length of 8 and max of 30 but it doesn't work, can someone lead me in the right direction please thanks! **(Line 9)**

```
 <?php ob_start( ); ?>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Teacher Registeration</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form method='POST'  action='TeacherRegisterCheck.php'>
            Email:<input type="email" id= "Email" name="teacherEmail" required /><br><br>
            Password:<input type="password" pattern=".{8,30}" id= "Password" name="teacherPassword" required title=" 8 to 30 characters" /><br><br>
            First Name:<input type="text" id= "First_Name" name="teacherfName" required /><br><br>
            Last Name:<input type="text" id= "Last_Name" name="teacherlName" required /><br><br>
            <label for="Title"> Title: </label> <select name="Title">
                <option selected="" value= "Default"> (Select A Title) </option>
                <option value= "Mr">Mr.</option>
                <option value= "Mrs">Mrs.</option>
                <option value= "Miss">Miss.</option>
                <option value= "Ms">Ms.</option>            
                <option value= "Dr">Dr.</option>
                <option value= "Master">Master.</option> </select> </br></br>           
             <button type="submit"> Enter </button>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
    <?php
```

Comment: What is the behavior you're seeing? What browser and version are you using?

Comment: Works in FireFox 57. Could be browser specific. http://jsbin.com/pupuxoqome/edit?html,console,output

Comment: It doesn't check just goes to the next php file and I'm using Google Chrome 61.0.3163.100

Comment: Works in Chrome as well. https://ibb.co/b2yxam  Your problem is probably elsewhere.

Comment: This should work in that browser version. Here's a fiddle demonstrating it: https://jsfiddle.net/xdwdk6d0/ I'm guessing the problem lies outside of the code pasted here. Is there some JS affecting this form?

Comment: Works on 60.0.3112.113, I don't think they'd rever the feature. Double check your source has the pattern as you expect. https://jsfiddle.net/vtuuoa9g/ Also if you really require the validation you should do it server side as well.

Comment: Na there's nothing else effecting code, it works in the jsfiddle for some reason but not my version of chrome. I'm using Xampp to run a localhost if that helps but I don't see how that would effect it. Also I don't have a server to run it server side.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue and you must not use `pattern` because does not have full cross browser support yet on some `iOS safari` and `Android browsers` might not work. I tried to find a workaround but I ended up that the safest solution is to check on client side via `Javascript` and of course server side with `PHP`.

Comment: I tried using javascript but I had an error and thought required and pattern would easier.

Comment: Of course it would be easier but the final goal is to be safe... :)
Remember that if you gonna use it in mobile browsers also, do not rely on theses HMTL5 directives. Derective required will not work also on some iOS safari versions. So use again JS and PHP checks for required fields.

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting.  `[.]` should match any non-linebreak character as I understand it, but for some reason fails here on passwords. I would suggest you be a little more explicit on how you match. For instance you can match against non-whitespace characters (example below), although this won't help if you plan to allow spaces in your passwords.  In that case you'd just need a more extensive allowable character list/pattern in your expression.

All that said, **never rely on front end validation alone**. Always do server side validation as well or in place of this.

```html
<form method='POST'  action='google.com'>
Password:
<input type="password" pattern="[^\s]{8,30}" id= "Password" name="teacherPassword" required title=" 8 to 30 characters" /><br><br>         
<button type="submit"> Enter </button>
</form>
```

Comment: I tried your alterations but it didn't help. Thanks anyway! Also I was wondering what  the [^\s] does as I'm still new to HTML and PHP.

Comment: Interesting. did you run the snippet?  It works there.  Maybe you have other elements in your code coming into play.  Since you asked [^\s] matches any non-whitespace character.  https://regex101.com/r/yq0O3E/1

Answer (score -1):

use minlength="8" and maxlength="30"

Comment: `minlength` is not a valid attribute

Comment: @Eathen00 reeeeaaalllllllly?  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp

Comment: @bassxzero It is an HTML5 attribute, don't go to w3schools as a authoritative source. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input or https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#setting-minimum-input-length-requirements:-the-minlength-attribute